# How to migrate from TDS to CLI

Tags: tds, sitecore-cli

I have an existing project that uses TDS and now we have to use CLI instead.
Either in the code or the "serialization" folders, I could not find any config file which mentions that paths of all the items that are to be serialized.

Because, an additional challenge for us is to also find out what are the items that need to be serialized.

When I opened one of the project files, I see this, but it is difficult from here to know which item and to be included with child items or not.

[image]

Is there any way I could find the list of items & rules, which were configured to be serialized. I could then use the same to configure Sitecore CLI.

We are using 10.1.3 on managed cloud.

Any other help for this migration is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few tools/scripts that can help parse through your TDS project and convert them to the equivalent configuration for Sitecore Content Serialization (SCS):

- [Get-PathsFromTds.ps1](https://gist.github.com/bic742/f77783c643420b704535d88fcbb5b18e): A powershell script by Sitecore MVP Aaron Bickle to generate SCS JSON files. Does not support role migration.
- [Sitecore Serialization Converter](https://github.com/josephjlong/sitecore-serialisation-converter): A .NET application by Sitecore Solution Architect Joseph Long that you can configure to parse through TDS projects and generate SCS JSON files. Supports role migration but does not migrate role inheritance.

These tools may not cover every single use case. You will likely need to extend them to your needs. You should also note that these convert the project configurations, but they do not deploy content during this step. You will do this in the next step.

You could also do this manually, but I would recommend using a tool to get started so you have less work to do overall.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it indeed in the project file that you opened.

There are 2 settings for every item in the project file, like in the first line of your file:

[image]

First one is `ItemDeployment`. Options there are `NeverDeploy`, `DeployOnce` or `AlwaysUpdate`. I think they are self-explanatory.

Second one is `ChildItemSynchronization`. Options there are `NoChildSynchronization` and `KeepAllChildrenSynchronized`. If `KeepAllChildrenSynchronized` options is chosen, whetever is in the project file it will be deserialized when you run TDS sync. If an item is already in Sitecore and it's not in the project, it will be removed from Sitecore.