TDS item migration/transform to yml
I have an old project that has a TDS Project and implicit lots of .item files.
I found the way how to migrate the TDS Project to the equivalent configuration for SCS using the answers from here https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/36322/447
But is there a way to migrate/transform the .item files into .yml that are used by SCS? As I do not want to rebuild everything from scratch since I do not have a TDS license anymore.

Once your convert the configuration files, then you can use SCS commands for "dotnet ser pull" to pull all the latest files on to your local from your sitecore instance.
Please ensure your sitecore instance is upto date with latest content or restore databases into your local sitecore instance.

Well, probably I should have mentioned that I only have the source code for this old project, and since I do not have a TDS license I can not put the TDS serialized items into a Sitecore instance. So I can not use "dotnet sitecore ser pull"

I believe you are in a deadlock situation here @SebastianTecsi, because either TDS License or a DB with those items would be a requirement.

Follow these 3 steps
Convert TDS to Text (.txt): Change TDS files to text format.
Convert Text to CSV: Extract key-value pairs from text and save as CSV.
Create Sitecore Items: Use CSV data (Sitecore PS extension) to create Sitecore items and generate .sc files.
